# Spying on a method which calls another api method internally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have a function inside a controller, which calls a method of an object "mapping".

```
$scope.createParameter = function (parameter) {
  var apiObj = {};
  mapping.createApiService(apiObj)
}
```

that object structure is as follows, and this method 'createApiService' calls a 'create' method of apiService.

```
var mapping = {
  createApiService : apiService.create
}
```

I have injected that apiService into my Testsuite. and a spyon is also been added as follows.

```
spyOn(apiService, "create").and.callFake(function () {
  return {
    then: function (callback) {
      callback(createResponse);
      return {
        catch: function () {
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

but when I execute my it block with following expectation it gives an error "expected spy create to have been called.

```
expect(apiService.create).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

can some one help me with this?

**EDIT**: Added testing code

```
describe("Controller", function () {

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("ui.router"));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("PpmApp"));

    var $controller, $scope, $state, $httpBackend, parameterDetails, apiService, constantsProvider;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$state_, _$httpBackend_, _apiService_, _constantsProvider_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $state = _$state_;
        $scope.header = {};
        $state.current = {};
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        apiService = _apiService_;
        constantsProvider = _constantsProvider_;
        $controller = $controller("Controller", { "$scope": $scope, "parameterDetails": parameterDetails });
    }));

   describe("create", function () {

        it("should succeed with valid Input", function () {
            var parameter = {
                ParameterType: 1,
                ParameterId: 2,
                LookupCurveStructures: [{
                    Name: "Parameter name",
                    XAxisName: "XAxisName",
                    YAxisName: "YAxisName",
                    XAxisDataType: 1,
                    YAxisDataType: 2
                }]
            };

            var createResponse = {
                Data: [],
                IsSuccess: true,
                Message: "Parameter added successfully"
            };

            spyOn(apiService, "create").and.callFake(function () {
            return {
              then: function (callback) {
                callback(createResponse);
                  return {
                    catch: function () {
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            });
            $scope.createParameter(parameter);
            expect($scope.createPopupInfo.validationErrors.isError).toEqual(false);
            expect(apiService.create).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect($scope.parameterDetails.Parameters).toEqual([]);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you instantiate the `apiService` in your test?

Comment: I have injected apiService in the beforeEach block

Comment: Ok ... idk man, I don't see anything wrong with the code blocks you added ... we need more code please

Comment: @Protozoid which code do you specifically want to see? from the controller, from the api service or from the spec?

Comment: The tests code to begin with please

Comment: its a quit big chunk of code, let me create a fiddle for that

Comment: https://codepen.io/nileshmahaja/pen/PamWXa?editors=0010 here you can check the test code

Comment: That helped a lot. I think the issue is that you haven't actually injected `apiService`. You need to do the same as you did with e.g. parameterApiService. Inject it in the beforeEach with `_apiService_` and store it in a global variable.

Comment: @Protozoid I have corrected the code in the fiddle, please check

Comment: Did that fix the issue?

Comment: No, it was a typo in the fiddle, In my actual test case file was not a problem.

Comment: Can you try adding some `console.log`s in all your function calls and remove the spy to see if they're actually getting called? There's nothing obviously wrong in your code ...

Comment: Instead of the mapping.apiService if I use direct api call, it works perfectly alright. but not with object method